# Fiddler to use https by default

Tags: https, fiddler, fiddler-dev

I need to install fiddler on multiple machines, and I need to enable https by default and install the certificate by itself. I don't want to do it manually using the UI.

Is there such an option ?

Or, is there a command line I use to install the certificate ? I can enable https mode by changing it in the registry directly, but I still need to install the certificate. I tried winhttpcertcfg but it installs the certificate in the Root instead of Personal store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation of this scenario is not presently an officially supported operation.

You can have an installer/batch file create a self-signed root for Fiddler to use, then have it automatically installed in Windows' Trusted Store. 
Note you'll need to do this from an elevated command prompt.

```
makecert -ss my -n "CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com" -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -r -a sha1 -cy authority

certmgr /add /c /s my /n DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot /s root
```